# Transpose rows to column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have data in a single column that I want to transpose to a single row in SQL Server 2012. This data comes from more than one table.

Please help me **without** using pivot function.

My data like this:

```
p1
x1 
y1 
z1
```

I want to change it into

```
p1 x1 y1 z1
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a pivot? that's exactly what the pivot expression is for

Comment: I dont know  exactly how to use pivot so Idont want to use it

Comment: Actually thinking about it unless you have an aggregate a pivot won't work anyway.

Comment: Ihave not any aggeregation function in my query Idont need it

Comment: @SamuelO'Connor See below.

Comment: Well done @JohnCappelletti - That's along the same lines I was thinking but forgot about dynamic SQL for the column names

Comment: @SamuelO'Connor Thanks, but I'm still struggling to see the value here

Comment: @JohnCappelletti what do you mean? Your answer doesn't work?

Comment: @SamuelO'Connor Sorry, I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti yeah I know it works, I upvoted your answer

Comment: I changed the title to `Transpose rows to columns` as that is actually what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: can you "transpose" in this way? `select  (select top 1 somefield_p from ... where ... order by ...) as p1,
  (select top 1 somefield_x from ... where ... order by ...) as x1,
  (select top 1 somefield_y from ... where ... order by ...) as y1,
  (select top 1 somefield_z from ... where ... order by ...) as z1
` this is valid for some situations, may be your case ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(SomeColumn) From YourTable Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
 Select ' + @SQL + '
  From  (Select SomeColumn from YourTable ) A
  Pivot (max(SomeColumn) For [SomeColumn] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
p1  x1  y1  z1
p1  x1  y1  z1
```

Would you rather have Col1,Col2,..ColN

Comment: there is no result when iam trying this way and there is no error

Comment: @Sara Did you replace all "SomeColumn" with your actual column name and "YourTable" with your table name ?  Any NULL in your field?  How many records?

Comment: Yes i replace all this ,there is no null feilds in my table , but its very complicated because my querey is very long

Comment: @Sara in that case, I would keep your complicated query as is, but drop the results into a temp table i.e. #Temp (Select ... into #temp From ,,,) and then replace YourTable with #temp

Answer (score 0):

To pivot without using the T-SQL pivot function you could do this:

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE (col1 char(2), col2 int);
INSERT @yourtable (col1, col2) VALUES ('p1',20),('x1',30),('y1',15),('z1',3),('z1',5);

-- Pivoting without using Pivot
SELECT 
  p1   = MAX(CASE col1 WHEN 'p1' THEN col2 ELSE 0 END),
  x1   = MAX(CASE col1 WHEN 'x1' THEN col2 ELSE 0 END),
  y1   = MAX(CASE col1 WHEN 'y1' THEN col2 ELSE 0 END),
  z1   = MAX(CASE col1 WHEN 'z1' THEN col2 ELSE 0 END)
FROM @yourtable;
```

Results:

```
p1          x1          y1          z1
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
20          30          15          5
```